# Swinject UIViewController instantiated via nib not being dependency injected

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, swinject

An ordinary view controller like this:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController
{
    var someProperty: SomeProperty
    // etc...
}
```

Registered for [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/) thus:

```
defaultContainer.registerForStoryboard( SomeViewController.self )
{
    r, vc in
    vc.someProperty = r.resolve( SomeProperty.self )!
}
```

Then programmatically instantiated thus:

```
let someVC = SomeViewController( nibName: "SomeNib", bundle: nil )
```

Before being added to the view stack, never has `someProperty` injected.

What am I doing wrong, please? Thank you.

Comment: If you use a nib, you don't use `registerForStoryboard` but normal `register` and `resolve` pair on a container to get the view controller.

Comment: Thanks @Yoichi I'll try that when I get time and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Did you find a solution?